# Python Twisted How do I determine an absolute URL?

Tags: python, twisted

I need to generate an absolute URL to a resource while handling a web request in Twisted. The host, port, and protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) can all vary based on deployment, so it would be really convenient to look things up dynamically.

The URL I need to is a modification of the url of the resource currently being processed with all arguments stripped away, so just finding the full request URL would help a lot.

In other words, I know "/path/foo", but how do I find "http://example.com:8080"?

Comment: Http sends a `Host:` header. This can be of use if you want to find out what the browser thinks your url is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Request`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.server.Request.html) passed in to lots of Twisted Web server APIs has a `URLPath` method that returns an instance of `twisted.python.urlpath.URLPath`.  The [string representation](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-13.1.0/twisted/python/urlpath.py#L113) of a `URLPath` instance is a string like "http://example.com:8080/foo/bar".

Comment: And I'm an idiot who just missed that in the docs, mostly because I was expecting a member, not a method. Thanks!